# Передача параметров ссылок

Tags: jquery, html, javascript

Добрый день! У меня, друзья, к вам вопросы. Есть, значит, сайт, на котором есть несколько ссылок типа:

```
<a href="#" class="go" data-extend="param_norm" class="spec_button"></a>
<a href="#" class="go" data-extend="param_optima" class="spec_button"></a>
<a href="#" class="go" data-extend="param_prof" class="spec_button"></a>
```

В параметр data-extend передается специальное значение, которое необходимо для вариации принятия решения в скрипте по расчету стоимости тарифа.

По клику получается значение этого параметра:

```
$('a.go').click( function(event){ // ловим клик по ссылки с id="go"
            event.preventDefault(); // выключаем стандартную роль элемента
            $('#overlay').fadeIn(400, // сначала плавно показываем темную подложку
             function(){ // после выполнения предъидущей анимации
                  name_input = false;
                  email_input = false;
                  TypePay = $(".go").attr('data-extend');   
                  console.log(TypePay);               
                $('#modal_form') 
                    .css('display', 'block') // убираем у модального окна display: none;
                    .animate({opacity: 1, top: '50%'}, 200); // плавно прибавляем прозрачность одновременно со съезжанием вниз
            });
          });
```

Как видно, в TypePay передается этот параметр, а затем выводится в консоль. Почему вне зависимости от того, какую ссылку нажали, всегда в консоль выдает `param_norm`, ведь есть ссылки, где параметр равен `param_optima` или `param_prof`?

Самое смешное, в песочнице все работает, а на сайте нет(. http://jsfiddle.net/whsLom5g/6/

Comment: Обернуть бы всё в объект, и всё встаёт [на свои места](http://jsfiddle.net/sergiks/whsLom5g/9/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Атрибут ID у любого элемента должен быть уникальным. У вас данный атрибут одинаков для каждой ссылки, поэтому jQuery выполняет операции только с первой найденной ссылкой. Попробуйте так:

```
<a href="#" data-extend="param_norm" class="go spec_button"></a>
<a href="#" data-extend="param_optima" class="go spec_button"></a>
<a href="#" data-extend="param_prof" class="go spec_button"></a>
```

Кусок JS:

```
$('a.go').click( function(event){ // ловим клик по ссылки с class="go"
            event.preventDefault(); // выключаем стандартную роль элемента
            $('#overlay').fadeIn(400, // сначала плавно показываем темную подложку
             function(){ // после выполнения предъидущей анимации
                  name_input = false;
                  email_input = false;
                  TypePay = $(this).attr('data-extend');   
                  console.log(TypePay);               
                $('#modal_form') 
                    .css('display', 'block') // убираем у модального окна display: none;
                    .animate({opacity: 1, top: '50%'}, 200); // плавно прибавляем прозрачность одновременно со съезжанием вниз
            });
          });
```

Answer (score 1):

Это логично, так как id не может повторяться.
Задайте для ссылок, например, `data-role="select"`.
Вместо `$('a#go').click(...` напишите `$('a[data-role=select]').click(` и вместо этого  `TypePay = $("#go").attr('data-extend');` напишите `TypePay = $(this).attr('data-extend');`.

Comment: Да я исправил, это старый вариант, верстальщик просто дал мне такую верстку с одинаковыми id и логику написал, соответственно, так. С классами тоже не работает.

Comment: Можете показать сейчас полный код?